# Отсутствие множественного числа для слова "добро"

Tags: психология, грамматика

То есть русский может выбрать *меньшее из двух зол*, а вот выбрать большее из двух добр? добров? - уже никак: *от добра добра не ищут*.

Налицо заниженная самооценка, неверие в возможность удачи, везения, сомнение в собственных силах. Лично мне данное обстоятельство кажется серьёзным препятствием на пути нашего национального развития.

Как вы полагаете, коллеги, можем ли мы, объединив усилия, выправить этот застарелый вывих?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именительный - **дОбра**. Родительный - **добр**. 
Обе формы, как и остальные падежи множественного, за пределами грамматической нормы, но это не мешает рассматривать их на предмет принадлежности к той или иной парадигме - в исследовательских целях хотя бы.

Такую парадигму дает Зализняк, да оно и понятно, средний род, второе (школьное) склонение.
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE

Причин видеть между Б и Р беглую гласную нет никаких. Мы же не говорим "будь добёр"?!

Ну а что касается причин для отсутствия этой формы в числе грамматических правильных, тут все сказано. Подобные отвлеченные существительные множественного обычно не имеют. "Зло" - оно тоже почти не используется во множественном за пределами фразеологизма (или как там это сочетание правильно классифицировать). Даже трудно сказать, как будет именительные множественного - Зла? злы? зОлы? (вернее всего - как раз последнее, имхо, вопреки Зализняку).

Сравнить, например со словом любовь. Множественного словари не дают, или отмечают его разговорный характер. Но это не помешало Маяковскому написать про "миллионы огромных, чистых ***любовей***".

Comment: ДОбра? Отлично, спасибо! Жаль, что нельзя принять ещё один ответ.


А Маяковский в данном случае (и как это с ним нередко случалось) "не туда обулся": Любови - это форма Р.п. и Д.п имени собственного. Получается, он написал о миллионах девушках по имени Любовь, рослых, дородных и только что вышедших из бани. :D

О чувствах нужно было написать "много любвей".

Comment: Насчет форм "любвей" вы совершенно правы, Зализняк поддтверждает, но я говорил не о конкретной форме, а о крайней редкости, на грани неупотребительности мночественного числа вообще.

Answer (score 4):

Я вас утешу: "зло" тоже не имеет множественного числа, за исключением приведенного вами фразеологизма. А фраза "из двух добр большее" языку не нужна, поскольку она бессмысленная.

У языка нет вывихов, вывихи есть у некоторых его носителей...

Comment: "Я вас утешу"
Вот спасибо))))

Носители определённого психического склада любые изменения принимают в штыки. Но в ближайшее время штыки придётся отомкнуть: Ванга (и не только она) предрекла России тотальное процветание. Которое обрушится на нас буквально за ближайшим поворотом. Нужно же как-то морально готовиться, вот хоть мн. ч. для добра придумать. И держать карман шире!

Comment: Верно.  У  пары  зло-добро  нет  мн.  числа.  Так  что  они  в  этом  плане  равны.  Но  зло  видимо  более  многолико,  что  и  было  отражено  в  этом  фразеологизме.

Answer (score 4):

"Все счастливые семьи счастливы одинаково". "Добро" не нуждается во множественном числе, так как уже обозначает совокупность добрых дел. Множественное число в этом случае обозначало бы уже совокупность совокупностей, что ещё приемлемо для конкретных вещей (*толпы, груды и пр.*), но никак не для абстрактных моральных категорий, претендующих на универсальность. Если люди конфликтуют из-за того, что у них разное понимание, что такое "добро", то об этом скажут, что у каждого своя *правда*. Истины же и добра много не бывает.

Comment: Это мы, русские, так считаем. В голливудских фильмах русские не всегда выглядят отталкивающе, но всегда необаятельны, эмоционально зажаты и, как следствие, неудачливы. Вспомнить хоть фильм "2012".

Понятно, что Америка - наш самый заклятый друг, но всё же какая-то сермяжная правда в их вИдении есть. Надо как-то бороться.


Между прочим, в английском и французском множественное число для добра есть (goods, bienes). Правда, в значении "вещи, имущество", но тем не менее. Добры, они и есть добры.

Comment: Есть  такое  слово  "добруши"  или  "добрушки",  тоже  по  отношению  к  вещам,  представляющим  ценность  только  для  отдельных  людей.  Не  слыхали?

Comment: Нет, не слыхала. Должно быть, это диалектное слово. Очень милое.)))

Answer (score 2):

Зло многолико, а добро едино, оно воспринимается как абсолют.

Народная мудрость говорит нам, что не стоит подвергать сомнению то доброе, что человек имеет, или отвергать его, ожидая лучшего, потому что "кони от овса не рыщут  и от добра добра не ищут".

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.

Comment: Но  наличие  нескольких  видов  добра  всё  хе  можно  представить.  Как  и  видов  зла.  Из  двух  зол выбираем  меньшее  -  это  практически  идиома.  Зеркальный  антоним  не  обязателен.  Можно  сказать  как  Остап  Бендер: "Из  двух  зайцев  выбираем  того,  который  пожирнее !"